# Can't see my custom extension on Azure Devops Marketplace

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions, azure-marketplace

**My issue**

I created an Azure Devops extension task. Deploy it on a publisher, shared it. But I can't find it on the MarkePlace.

**What I did**

This is my project:

[image]

This is my **task.json**:

```
{
  "id": "0f6ee401-2a8e-4110-b51d-c8d05086c1d0",
  "name": "deployRG",
  "category": "Utility",
  "visibility": [
    "Build",
    "Release"
  ],
  "demands": [],
  "version": {
    "Major": "0",
    "Minor": "1",
    "Patch": "0"
  },
  "instanceNameFormat": "DeployRG $(name)",
  "groups": [],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "name": "Name",
      "type": "string",
      "label": "RG name",
      "defaultValue": "",
      "required": true,
    }
  ],
  "execution": {
    "PowerShell3": {
      "target": "CreateRG.ps1"
    }
  }
}
```

My manifest vss-extension.json:

```
{
    "manifestVersion": 1,
    "id": "deployRG",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "name": "Deploy RG",
    "publisher": "Amethyste-MyTasks",
    "public": false,
    "categories": [
        "Azure Pipelines"
    ],
    "tags": [
        "amethyste"
    ],
    "contributions": [
        {
            "id": "DeployRG",
            "type": "ms.vss-distributed-task.task",
            "targets": [
                "ms.vss-distributed-task.tasks"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "DeployRG"
            }
        }
    ],
    "targets": [
        {
            "id": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services"
        }
    ],
    "files": [
        {
            "path": "DeployRG",
            "packagePath": "DeployRG"
        },
    {
        "path": "VstsTaskSdk"
    }
    ]
}
```

**What I checked**

I am owner of the organization and belong to **Project Collection Administrators** group.

On the portal:

[image]

On the publisher portal:

[image]

**What I need**

I checked some tutorial on Internet and can't see what I do wrong.
Has anybody an idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Aargh, I have just found and its easy.

After sharing, one should install the extension as indicated here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/publish/overview?view=azure-devops

Don't know why so many tutorials skip this step